# SharedPreferences editor not executing

Tags: java, android

In the following piece of code, one of the mEditor lines, doesn't appear to execute. 

I've tried many different combinations so far, but can't get it to execute properly. The value is not set at all. 
If i try to use the value, like in a Toast, I will receive a ResourcesNotFound Exception

Initialization of SharedPreference in my onCreateView, Fragment

```
mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
```

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

        int round_number = mSharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.pref_round_played),0);
if (round_number == 0){
            game_team.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.t);
            game_team.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            knap_bund.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            knap_top.setText("Next Strat");
            mEditor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_chosen_team), "T");
            mEditor.putInt(getString(R.string.pref_round_played),round_number + 1);
            mEditor.apply();
               //Show CT side Pistol round here//
            }
```

Following code is used in my onClick, which has other sharedPreferences, working the exact same way, which executes fine.
The first line executes just fine, but the second line containing 'putInt' isn't executing as intended.

```
mEditor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_chosen_team), "T");
mEditor.putInt(getString(R.string.pref_round_played), 1);
mEditor.apply();
```

Example of working code:

```
    else if(round_number <= 30){
            mEditor.putInt(getString(R.string.pref_round_played),round_number + 1);
            mEditor.apply();
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Just to clarify due to the comments. It's only this one occasion where the sharedPreferences won't work. I use it about 15 other places in this fragment, with no issues at all

Comment: you should `commit`

Comment: Plese post your full code and error log here.

Comment: @AlanDeep That doesn't make a difference in this case. Same result

Comment: What is `getString()` ? You are using a language translatable key ? Why are you using a string resource as key ?

Comment: How did you try to get the vale? Put your code here...

Answer (score 0):

> I will receive a ResourcesNotFound Exception

I think `R.string.pref_round_played` is not exist,check it for your `strings.xml`
you're not posted for your detailed code so do it like this below to save values in shared preference

```
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME , MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "john");
 editor.putInt("id", 123);
 editor.apply();
```

Retrieve the data from shared preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("name", ""); // you can put default value if you need
int idName = prefs.getInt("id", 0);
```

if this is not works for you please post your full code

**Update**

change your code to this one

```
mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
       SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences .edit();
```

Comment: I've added a bit of more explanation. All my sharedPreferences are stored, via string resources, in my `string.xml` file